# How to distinguish between firebase email auth user & firebase google auth user in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for authentication and I need to keep Delete Screen differently for Google Auth Users and Email Auth Users since the Google Auth Users don't need to provide their passwords. So, I wanted to know does FirebaseAuth offers some function that can distinguish if the user has used email or Google for Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out what provider a specific user account was created with from its [`FirebaseUser.providerId` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserInfo/providerId.html).

If you use account linking to allow a single user to sign in with multiple providers, you'll have to iterate over the [`FirebaseUser.providerData` array](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/providerData.html) and check the `UserInfo.providerId` for each of them.

The following function should help out in returning "password" for Firebase Email Auth users or "google.com" for Google Auth Users.

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
. . . . 
. . . .
. . . .
Future<String> getAuthType() async {
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    String authType = firebaseUser.providerData[1].providerId;
    return authType;
}
```

You can use this information to your own advantage and create your widgets or Screens accordingly!